# Coupling two motors to get more Power

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Can I couple two motors on the same shaft to get more power, in order words if I couple two 5HP motors on the same shaft will I get more then 5HP at the shaft. If yes what calculation will I have to do to figure out the output at the shaft.

Comment: 2 * 5  is a start, but the detailed control will be the challenge otherwise you loose power if one is driving the other...

Comment: 2*5 if they are absolutely identical (no two things really are), and you were getting 5 hp at half the torque but same RPM as case you want to run with two coupled, and your structural components can handle the load.  Track down how your specific case differs from that ideal (speed vs torque curves, structural check on shaft, the loading from what your motors will power)

Comment: If the motors are coupled with a differential, they can turn at different rates and there will only be a small power loss from friction.